# Gnuplot Plotting Multiple Interpolated Surfaces in One Image

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to visualize results from varying three different parameters using gnuplot. I can produce a 4D plot by using an xyz scatter plot with color as the fourth dimension. Now what I want to do is to take the limited data I have and produce higher quality images. As seen below, if I angle the 4D plot in just the right way I can get what looks like a series of 3D plots along one dimension. Is there a way I can individually interpolate these 3D slices and obtain smoothed planar surfaces for the cross-sections instead of the scatter plot form I currently have?

4D Scatter Plot Angled to Look Like 3D Cross-Sections:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New in version 5.4 (please try and report on the release candidate!)

http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.4/voxel.html

[image]